Windows 11 Pro not releasing memory of closed program
Problem: Windows 11 Pro takes up complete memory (27 to 32GB) within 2-3 days of working

Memory Diagnostic Found no issues
Most tweaks done as suggested online in many different websites.
Reinstalled and clean reinstalled Windows

I noticed in RamMap processes, the closed programs are listed as many times they were opened and closed. each item has minimum 28K of memory and that adds up slowly consuming complete memory. This happens quickly working on docker+wsl2+vscode.
After clean reinstall, today, the issue persists. I recorded a video after closing all programs, please watch by clicking here..
In the video you can notice the following...

Initial memory 5.7GB (No application running)
Action of Empty Working Sets reduces memory to 3.0/3.5GB
Refresh in RAMMap moves the memory to 4.5GB
The closed program references are still visible in process lists
At last see no program or user application running ... (except 4 required to record..)

Question: Is the above behaviour normal?
If not, I will appreciate any suggestion to resolve it...
===========
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
Windows Version 23H2(OS Build 22631.3447)
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 8600G w/ Radeon 760M Graphics
Board: MSI PRO B650M-P (MS-7E27)


Does this answer your question? Why is unused memory counted as used at the same time?

No. The issue is memory is not released by Windows. In 2-3 days of usage complete RAM is consumed even with only 2-3 user mode programs running.

The question is what does "consumed" mean. If the computer doesn't slow down progressively, you're only seeing the cache memory in action.

Does this have any practical effect? Are applications running mode slowly?

You're not answering the question: After the 3 days, does the computer slow down to a crawl or apps are still working just about normally?

Yes @harrymc, on third day, I notice very slow movement of cursor and switching between windows.... so I investigate and need to restart the pc..

If you have a memory leak in a system driver, RAMMap will not see it since it's operating in user space and not in kernel space. Perhaps it's better to reboot every night.

With win10, restart was only when win update requires it... always hibernate and work continue next day!!!

You should be looking at applications and/or services that are running when the computer slows. It is unlikely this problem is CAUSED by the OS, but is more likely due to an application that is misbehaving and/or causing a memory leak. All of the memory being in use MAY be an indicative symptom, but it may also NOT be an indicative symptom. Look at the processes and see if that helps illuminate this problem further.

I had an identical issue.
Given your hardware, I assume you have AMD Adrenalin installed?
If yes, check out this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1841517/183887

Thank you. My hardware is latest to that of talked on.... driver version 23.10.* is not supported on AMD 8600G. Also disabling iGPU is not an option as it's in use for display. I'm already in communication on github topic!!

@jd4u Hmm, you're using both GPUs? Why?

No. Only using Integrated GPU. No additional GPU on board. That is why disabling iGPU and using PEG is not possible/option in my case.

@jd4u roger that. Makes sense now.
